# Accessing SharePoint REST API behind auto-accelerated URL

Tags: rest, sharepoint

We have enterprise connector that has been designed and developed to access SharePoint resources via standard REST API calls from our platform to SharePoint. The authentication mechanism utilized by the enterprise connector is a standard OAuth 2.0 authentication using Client ID, Client Secret and resource to obtain an access token from a known IDP (accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net). The access token obtained in the previous call is used, as an Authorization header, for authorization to the SharePoint instance in subsequent REST API calls. The REST API requests are sent to a direct SharePoint URL (i.e. ourcompany.sharepoint.com) and are serviced by that service instance.

In the case of trying to use the standard enterprise connector with the SharePoint Online instance for this customer, the SharePoint URL that we have been instructed to send API requests to is an internal URL and is using Auto-Acceleration. All requests to this URL are forwarded to a federated authentication system maintained by the customer. All API requests sent to this URL are answered with  error code -2147024891 System.UnauthorizedAccessException - "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource." This is the also the case when sending API requests from a tool such as Postman - as to eliminate the authentication used by the enterprise connector as root cause of the access denial.

The solution we're seeking is the proper avenue to access the REST API services on this SharePoint Online instance. Is there a different authentication mechanism required in this scenario? Are there different API endpoints required to access SharePoint resources in this situation? Additional configuration required to allow access?

Any suggestions and/or guidance are appreciated.